# jqGrid add label close to input

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

In the [form editing documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing) of jqGrid it shows a Date field with a text hint at right.

I can't found the parameter to put that text, how can I add a hint at right of text box?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Show you basically want to change the hint text for form of jqGrid.

JqGrid provides an option in the form of `formoptions` which needs to be defined in the column you want to configure,

Derived from JqGrid Documentation [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#formoptions),

```
jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid({
...
   colModel: [ 
      ... 
      {name:'price', ..., formoptions:{elmprefix:'(*)',elmsuffix :'yyyy-mm-dd', rowpos:1, colpos:2....}, editable:true },
      ...
   ]
...
});
```

And i have prepared a [Demo JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jqJch/71/) to simply add an **astriek** on the form element as stated in the jqGrid example.

So you can use the below properties for further purpose,

1. **elmprefix** : if set, a text or html content appears before the input element
2. **elmsuffix** : if set, a text or html content appears after the input element
3. **label**     : if set, this replace the name from colNames array that appears as label in the form.

Comment: I agree in general, but to answer the question "how can I add a hint at right of text box?" one should use `elmsuffix` instead of `elmprefix` like `formoptions: {elmsuffix: '&nbsp;yyyy-mm-dd'}`

Comment: Yes i thought he was looking for the documentation of such implementation and which i have have mentioned in my answer.. But hey thanks for the follow through i will update my answer.